# Как размещаются стековые переменные в C

Tags: c, gdb, x86-64

Здравствуйте. Я копаюсь с помощью отладчика в коде, и пытаюсь понять по какому принципу GCC (C-compiler) размещает переменные (локальные) в стеке. Сначала я думал что он проталкивает их в том же порядке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть встретил int auth_flag и толкает в стек, переменная соответственно получает больший адрес (т.к. стек растёт в направлении младших адресов). Потом password_buffer уже получает адрес меньше. Но когда я поменял их местами -- ничего не изменилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

auth_flag по прежнему получает адрес больше и (т.е. стоит ниже в стеке чем password_buffer). Я бы подумал что так и должно быть, но этот пример взял с книги, и там, когда автор меняет местами переменные, -- они меняются местами и в стеке. Книга за 2010 год, x32 архитектура, возможно GCC моложе.

Поясните почему так происходит, почему компилятор не даёт самому выбирать порядок размещения переменных и чем он "руководствуется" когда размещает переменные.

**GCC version: 4.9.2**

Comment: ты по ссылке передаешь переменные? (намек типа покажи исходник-то, а не скриншоты)

Comment: Компилятор имеет право вообще не размещать переменную в стеке, а положить её в регистр. Или объединить несколько переменных в одну. Или разложить одну переменную в несколько мест. C — не ассемблер, компилятор вовсе не обязан компилировать механически следуя тому, что вы написали.

Answer (score 6):

Посмотрите на это с другой стороны. Если компилятор поменяет местами эти две переменные в стеке, это повлияет как-то на Ваш код? ответ - скорее всего Вы даже не узнаете об этом. А раз так, значит компилятор может расставить в стеке переменные так, как ему кажется правильным. И эти правила порой такие сложные, что только разработчики компилятора и процессора могут их аргументировать.

Но есть случаи, когда компилятор может переставить ещё хитрее. Например, в так называемом [RVO](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2008/02/rvo-nrvo.html). Если в функции создается объект и он из нее возвращается, то компилятор может это увидеть и создать объект ещё в стеке вызывающей функции. Таким образом, экономится вызов конструктора копирования и деструктора.

Но вернемся к вопросу, почему компилятор все-таки переставляет переменные? Он может ставить переменные так, что бы они были выровнены по границе в 16 байт - таким образом получится ускорение.